# Proof ln(x) limit

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, functions

Goal: Prove that $ \lim_{x \to 0}\ln(x) = -\infty$.

Consider $x \in (0,1]$

Fix $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Examine $\ln(\frac{1}{2^{n}}) = \int\frac{1}{t} \leq U(\frac{1}{t},P)$

Where our partition $P$ is $P =${$\frac{1}{2^{n}},...,\frac{1}{8},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2},1$}

Then $U(f(t),P) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}(\frac{1}{2^{i}}-\frac{1}{2^{i-1}})*2^{i-1}=-n\geq \ln(\frac{1}{2^{n}})\forall n \in \mathbb{N} $

Now fix $N \in \mathbb{N}$ and let $M $ be $M = \frac{1}{2^{2N+2}}$. We have that ln is strictly increasing which necessitates that $x < M$ and then $\ln(x) < \ln(M) = \ln(\frac{1}{2^{2N+1}}) \leq \ln(2^{-2(N+1)})=\frac{-2(N+1)}{2}=-N-1<-N $

Thus we can make $\ln(x)$ less than any $-N \in \mathbb{N}$ as $x \to 0$.

I wrote this similarly to a proof we did in class and I guess I'm wondering why we have free choice of $M$ is it just like a $\delta$ in this proof or no? I'm a bit unsure about this proof.

Comment: Why don't you just say that $\ln (\frac 1 {2^{n}})=-n\ln 2 \to -\infty$ and use monotonicity  of the function. I have no idea why you want to consider Riemann integrals.

Comment: We can't use that property of ln I guess @KaboMurphy

Comment: In your first line, you have $x \to \infty$. I assume you mean $x \to 0$ instead. Also, instead of non-positive integral powers of $2$, are you allowed to non-positive integral powers of $e$ instead? This will give the results of $\ln$ of these values to exactly be negative integers.

Comment: No sadly we don't know anything about e^x other than exp(x) is the inverse of ln. Also fixed the infinity haha. The only things we can use are "basic" definitions.@JohnOmielan

Comment: @Christheyankee If you know that $e^x$ is the inverse of $\ln(x)$, i.e., $\ln(e^x) = x$, then as long as you know that $e \gt 1$, you can use negative powers of $e$ directly to make your proof simpler, as I suggested in my earlier comment. Will this work for you, or am I missing something?

Comment: @JohnOmielan I don't think I'm grasping what you're hinting at. I'm sorry this is all new to me. Where would I apply this?

Comment: @Christheyankee I meant you could use a partition of $e^{-n}$ for integers $n \le 0$, with each value decreasing from $1$ to $0$ as $-n$ gets smaller. Then you would have that $\ln(e^{-n}) = -n$ would be a decreasing sequence of integers, with no lower bound. It's similar to what you did, but I believe it's simpler & more straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

$\ln x$ is an  increasing function of $x$ for $x>0$  (see Footnote) so it suffices to show that $\ln (2^{-n})\to -\infty$ as natural number $n\to \infty$ (see Remark).

For $n\in \Bbb N$ we have $$(\bullet)\quad \ln (2^{-n})=\int_1^{2^{-n}}(1/t)dt=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\int_{2^{-j}}^{2^{-j-1}}(1/t)dt.$$ Now $2^{-j}<2^{-j-1},$ and when $t\in [2^{-j-1},2^{-j})$ we have $(1/t)>2^j.$ So $$\int_{2^{-j}}^{2^{-j-1}}(1/t)dt<\int_{2^{-j}}^{2^{-j-1}}(2^j)dt=$$ $$=(2^{-j-1}-2^{-j})(2^j)=-1/2.$$ Applying this to $(\bullet)$ we have $$\ln (2^{-n})<\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}(-1/2)=-n/2.$$

Footnote. If $0<x<y$ then $\int_x^y(1/t)dt>0 $, so $$\ln y=\int_1^y(1/t)dt=\int_1^x(1/t)dt+\int_x^y(1/t)dt>\int_1^x(1/t)dt=\ln x.$$

Remark. For $0<x<1$ let $V(x)$ be the largest $n\in \Bbb N\cup \{0\}$ such that $x\le2^{-n}$. Then $V(x)\to \infty$ as $x\to 0,$ and $\ln  x\le \ln (2^{-V(x)})\le -V(x)/2.$

Comment: This is like showing that $S(n)=\sum_{j=1}^n(1/j)\to \infty$ as $n\to \infty$.... E.g. $S(8)>1+(1/2)+(1/4+1/4)+(1/8+1/8+1/8+1/8)=5/2$, and in general, if $1<n\in \Bbb N$ then $S(2^{n})> (n+2)/2.$